# Bluehost - Convert current DB to innoDB?

Tags: innodb, bluehost

I was wondering if it was possible to convert my current Bluehost database used for a phpBB forum to innoDB? I have just updated to phpBB 3.1.3 and some of the extensions I am trying to use are "only supported by phpBB forums that use MySQL v4.0.1 or later with MyISAM and InnoDB table types."

I am using MySQL v5.5.40. I know nothing about the correct terminology or working with databases. Will I have to save the database in a different format? Please make any responses easy to understand and as comprehensive as possible as I am a novice and need all the help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

InnoDB is a store-engine, and it's related to tables, not to database. You can have a database with tables using InnoDB and MyISAM.

You can convert each table using this query

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Or you can achieve this using phpMyAdmin (user friendly) for example.

Comment: In this case, the extension is looking for similar topics as the one posted. I believe that it only searched topic titles. Does this mean I would have to convert only that table? How would I do this in phpMyAdmin? I am very new to all of this and do not want to screw up my database now that I have it working.

Comment: I don't know how really the plugin works under the hood, but first try on a local environment, and if all works good, reproduce those change on your server.

Comment: Thanks. All of that is beyond my understanding, but I appreciate the help.